# Angularjs display table paging in url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

is it possible to display the paging of a html table in the url? Would appreciate if someone could teach or gimme a link to learn about it. Can't seem to find it anywhere. Thanks!

Table code :

```
      <div id="btnDLContainer">

        <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tableToCsv')" type="button contact-button" class="btnDL">XLSX Download</button>
        <button export-to-csv class="btnDL">CSV Download</button>
        <table ng-show="auditoriums === 'none'">

                <tr> <th> Name </th> <th> Address Block No. </th> <th> Postal Code </th> <th> Street Name </th> </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="audit in auditoriums| limitTo: 1 - auditoriums.length">
                  <td>{{audit.NAME}}</td>
                  <td>{{audit.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER}}</td>
                  <td>{{audit.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE}}</td>
                  <td>{{audit.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
                </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/angularDirectiveInDOM) ?

Comment: i'll take a look at that, thanks~ @MadhanVaradhodiyil